# WebSocket with Spring Boot and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring-boot, websocket

This is my simple attempt to create a WebSocket channel between a JavaScript client and a Java server.

```
// java websocket server configuration with spring boot
// server port: 8080 set in the "application.yml"

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer{
    
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/websocket")
                .setAllowedOrigins("*")
                .withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {                
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
                .enableSimpleBroker("/notification");
    }   
}
```

```
// js websocket client configuration with "webstomp-client"

import webstomp from 'webstomp-client';

const connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/websocket');
const stompClient = webstomp.over(connection);
stompClient.connect(()=>{
  stompClient.subscribe('/app/notification', () => console.log('Connection established with server'));
});
```

The console shows the following:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

I looked at a lot of other posts, and most of them had to do with allowing the origin. I have tried setting the origin to `localhost` as well as the local IP address, but without success.

What am I missing? Any help would be tremendous.

***Edit:*** The client is created with `create-react-app`, if that's relevant.

***Edit:*** The client is on: `http:localhost:3000`, the server is on: `http:localhost:8080`.

Comment: Could you please show where you are handling the routes `app/notification` in your server?

Comment: @edkeveked I have a websocket controller class but it is not doing much at the moment. So I am not handling anything.

Comment: Maybe that this is where the problem comes from. Are you returning something to those that have subscribed with `app/notification`?

Comment: @edkeveked I don't think it even gets there. The channel closes before any subscription happens. Does it matter that client and server are on different ports? I wouldn't think so but Id mention it anyways.

Comment: What do you mean by client and server on different ports? Well, it is possible to have the client being served on `localhost:4200` and the server on `localhost:8080` for instance.
The last thing I could mention is maybe to remove the `.setAllowedOrigins("*")` and to set the CORS at a global level of your application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are configuring your endpoint with SockJS on the server side but you are not using SockJS on the client side. That's why you get a 200 status code instead of a 101. Either use SockJS on the client side (instead of a raw WebSocket) or remove `withSockJS()` on the server side.

Comment: Yes - this is it. I also found out last night by trial and error. I am gonna give you the check mark. In order to add sockjs support on the client - do I use the sockjs library instead?

Comment: Yes, add SockJS on the client and use `new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/websocket')` instead of `new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/websocket')`